# Why does MSVC x64 Compiler load addresses like this?

Tags: x86, x86-64, pointer, msvc

Normally, in x86, to load a pointer to a null-terminated string you would use

```
MOV EDX, OFFSET ds:mystring
```

In x64, however, I noticed that the compiler does it like this

```
lea rdx, OFFSET FLAT:$mystring ; 'it is ten'
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

If you disassemble the instructions for

```
mov edx, offset ds:mystring
```

vs

```
lea rdx, offset ds:mystring
```

You'll notice the LEA instruction length (in bytes) was smaller. Its a compiler optimization!

Or, it could be the compilers way of addressing pointer arithmetic in an easier manner.

Check out [this](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=64) for more info on both.

Comment: it's incorrect. [`mov edx, offset` is 5 bytes long, whereas `lea rax, offset` is 7 bytes long](https://godbolt.org/g/vkj2j9). The 64-bit version is longer partly due to the REX prefix

Comment: check the source i cited; its a known compiler trick that also relies on whether or not $RDX is treated as a pointer in his example. Generally the compiler will do this because its usually a shorter series of bytes (if $RDX is used as a pointer, of which most C++ functions do for string operations).

Comment: Your link doesn't even work. Checked the [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170623015202/http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=64) and I don't see it says LEA is shorter anywhere. Probably I copied the wrong Godbolt link in the comment above. [Here's another one](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/_RJNKm). One can clearly see that the compiler outputs a longer LEA. In fact [there are many `mov reg, imm` forms from 5 to 10 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48597025/995714). `mov reg, [mem]` will be longer if you need an SIB byte or REX prefix. Same to LEA

Comment: You need to read the instruction encoding from Intel's manual, not from a blog. Or check it from the real assembler output. You can also paste `mystring: mov edx, offset ds:mystring; lea rdx, [ds:mystring]
` into the [only assembler](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly) and see the output. The [LEA](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lea) version is always longer because the immediate must be encoded as the memory displacement. There's no `lea reg, imm` version like `mov reg, imm`

Comment: the link works.